# making announcement about giving up on main meals

Tags: phrase-request

Let's say I am making an announcement to the members of a chess club, at which we gather together every week for having lunch first and then playing chess. I want to inform them that this month there will be no lunches - only tea and snacks. Is "food intake" okay in this case?:

> This month, we will reduce our **food intake** to just tea and snacks.

Or does it sound too scientific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with:

> This month there will be no lunches - only tea and snacks.

Talking about "reducing food intake" does sound very medical, to the point of being sarcastic.

You might want to add some explanation of why there will be no lunch. Is this for health, religious or financial reasons.